# Magento 2.1.5: While adding Bundle items doesn't show all products for selection

Tags: magento2, admin, bundled-product

I am trying to add items in bundle product but it does not shows all products.

> NOTE: Tried for both options  required **Yes** and  required **No**

```
Products count: 5130
Simple Products: 5129
Visibility(Catalog, Search): 5129
Status(Enabled): 5129
```

When trying to add options for bundle product, 4135 products showing.

What should I do to show all products there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 scenarios to fix:

1) Some products has swatch images assigned, so I removed swatch images from those products then approx 100 products count increased.

2) Some products has **Customizable Options** assigned with checkbox  **Required -> True**, So I changes it to **Required -> False**.
Approx 900 products count increased.